# Cycle elimination constraint in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I'm working on a graph problem via mathematical programming. I need to add a set of constraints to remove all cycles. I found a very interesting paper which suggests a way to do it using a set of linear constraints, please see https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1202/1202.3713.pdf.

Here is what they did. Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, define a binary variable $I(W \rightarrow u)=1$ iff $W$ are the  parents  of $u$ in  an  optimal  graph.

"These class of constraints rests upon the observation that any subset $C$ of vertices in a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) must contain at least one vertex who has no parent in that subset [It can have a parent in an external subset]. These are called cluster-based constraints and can be expressed as linear constraints":

Then, the follwoing equation will remove all cycles in the graph.

$$\forall C \subseteq V \quad \sum_{u \in C} \sum_{W: W\cap C =\emptyset} I\{W \rightarrow u\} \geq 1.$$

I have difficulty to underestand these set of inequalities. For instance, consider the graph $(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,1), (5,1), (6,2), (7,3), (8,4)$. It seems to me that the set of equalities above does not remove the loop $1-2-3-4$. The author of this paper are quite expert in their domain. Hence, I assume that I misunderestood these set of inequalities :)

I would appreciate if someone gives a more intutive explanation, preferebly via an example.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that $W$ is a possible set of all "parents" (sources linked to) $u$. So the "parent sets" of nodes 1 through 4 are, respectively, {4, 5} (parents of 1), {1, 6}, {2, 7}, and {3, 8}. For the set $C = \{1,\dots,4\}$, no node in $C$ has a parent set disjoint from $C$; so for each $u\in C$ the inner summand is over an empty set of terms, and hence is zero.

There are simpler ways to remove cycles. If, in your model, $x_{ij}$ is a binary variable indicating that the arc $(i,j)$ was selected/is present, the constraint $$\sum_{i\in S, j\in S} x_{ij} \le |S|-1 \quad \forall S\subseteq V$$gets the job done. As with the constraints you asked about, a potential issue is that the number of constraints grows exponentially with the size of $V$. For a smaller approach (quadratic in the number of nodes), albeit one that produces a somewhat weaker relaxation, you might want to look at the [Miller-Tucker-Zemlin constraints](http://docs.mosek.com/6.0/capi/node015.html).

Comment: Thank you @prubin. It now makes sense what is going on. I fully agree with you. This is a better way to avoid cycles. By the way, I very much enjoy your blog; very informative!!

Comment: Just one important point. It seems that the inequality you provided is for the undirected graph. I am actually looking for a way to avoid cycles in a directed graph. Any thought? Appreciate it!

Comment: The inequality should work for directed graphs. A cycle among $n$ nodes involves $n$ directed arcs. The inequality limits all arcs within that $n$ node subset to at most $n-1$ selections.

Comment: That is true. But, it also excludes many other graphs which do not create cycles. For instance the directed graph G ={(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (1,4)} has no cycle. But, the proposed inequality i.e., x_{12} + x_{23} + x_{32} + x_{14} <= 3 violates this inequality although the graph does not have a directed cycle. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought you were trying to eliminate subtours while constructing a tour from a graph, not constructing the graph itself. The arcs you listed would violate the enter once/leave once constraints of a tour. Similarly, the MTZ constraints may be inappropriate if you're building the graph itself.

Comment: If you're building a digraph using a MIP model to pick the included arcs, and the exponential number of variables and constraints from the paper you cited gets to be too much, you might consider Benders decomposition. The master problem picks the arcs. The subproblem takes an alleged solution and looks for cycles (e.g., by testing whether any node can reach itself). If a cycle is found, the master problem adds a cut saying you can't have all the arcs in the cycle. Might be faster (no guarantee); likely would use less memory.

Comment: Thank you for your great suggestion! I will certainly look into the Bender Decomposition. At the same time, I realized we can change your constraint such that it removes all cycles from the graph. To achieve this, we can take all paths from node $p$ to node $q$. For each path, we add an inequality as follows: \sum_{(i,j) \in path} x_ij <= |S|-1. In this case, we take the order arcs. In my problem, fortunately, we need to remove all cycles that include a particular edge, say (p,q), hence I can write all paths in an undirected graph from p to q and impose this constraint.